# Segmentation fault 11 with pointers

Tags: c, arrays

why when attempt to use function N I get a Segmentation fault 11 .. im new to malloc so i dont exactly know where to look for my error .. im trying to read from a file and put certain line through fscanf to my double array ..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

void V(int *id,int i,int *praca, double *plat,int *datum, FILE **f)
{
char meno[2000],priezvisko[2000];

if ((*f = fopen("zam.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Neda sa otvorit");
    // koniec programu
    return ;         
}

while(//vypis informacii zamestnancov
fscanf(*f,"%d %s %s %d %lf   %d",&id[i],&meno[i],&priezvisko[i],&praca[i],&plat[i],&datum[i])>0)
{
printf(" osobne cislo zamestnanca:%d\n meno priezvisko:%s %s\n administrativa/vyrobny pracovnik:%d\n plat:%g\n datum:%08d\n\n",id[i],&meno[i],&priezvisko[i],praca[i],plat[i],datum[i]);
i++;
}


}  
void N(int i,double **platy, FILE *f)
{
    rewind(f);


    int j=0,k=0;
    char line[1800];
    int suma = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int lineNumber = 2;
    double val;
    double d;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)!= NULL)
    {

        if (count == lineNumber)
        {
            suma++; //pocet platov
            count++;
            lineNumber+=6;
            *platy=malloc(suma*sizeof(double));
            fscanf (f, "%lf", platy[i]);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("SUMA: %d",suma);
}

int main()                                      //MAIN
{

    int i=0,id[1800],praca[1800],datum[1800];
    char *meno[1800],*priezvisko[1800],z;
    double plat[1800],*platy;
    FILE *f;


    while((z = getchar())!='K')
    {
        if(z == 'V')
            V(id,i,praca,plat,datum,&f);
        if(z == 'P')
            P(i,praca,plat,datum,f);
        if(z == 'N')
            N(i,&platy,f);
    }

    /*
     for (j=0 ; j<suma; j++) {
     printf("%g\n",*platy[j]);
     }
     */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never open a file. `f` is not initialized when you send it to `N` for usage. It certainly isn't referring to a valid file stream. Running in a debugger would almost assuredly show you this, as would turning up your compiler warnings to pedantic levels and compiling with warnings-as-errors.

Comment: What is `V`? What is `P`? What was the test input? Please post a [mcve]. As it is, we do not know whether `f` is really uninitialised or whether `V` correctly initialised it prior to calling `N`. And suggest you use better variable and function names than single letters.

Comment: i use a different funcion to load the file i just didnt include the whole function which loads to avoid further chaos in my code

Comment: `fscanf (f, "%lf", platy[i])` --> `fscanf (f, "%lf", &((*platy)[i]))`. But note that your logic is wrong. Every time `malloc` is called you lose all the previous data in the previous memory and you leak the memory. Look up `realloc`.

Comment: Like @WhozCraig mentioned, f is not initialized by the time it's used in N.

`#1  0x00000000004008fe in N (i=0, platy=0x7ffffffeec98, f=0x0) at t.c:29`, 
the relevant part from the stack trace when run in GDB.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: variable names should indicate content or usage (or better, both).  Function names should indicate what the function does, usually be starting the function name with an active verb, followed by what the object is that is being acted upon.